# Insert date into sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My input date format is '%m-%d-%Y' (e.g: 12/12/2012) and my Query for executing

```
"Insert into employeedetails(FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,StartedDate,Salary,CompanyName)  values ('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+job+"',STR_TO_DATE('"+date+"', '%m-%d-%Y'),'"+salary+"','"+company+"')";
```

while executing query it throws error about incorrect format

When i manually inserting date in this format (2012-12-12) it's working so i need the conversion from 12/12/2012 to 2012-12-12

Comment: what the type of your StartedDate field on your table. You must consider it.

Comment: try this ...   DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y');

Comment: Can you share with us the exact data type for your database column. It could be DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE, etc..

Comment: Also I know you did not ask about it, but typically you have to add double quotes around uppercase column names.
"FirstName","LastName"

Comment: for mysql database, no need to convert to date format. you can pass it as string. database automatically converts it to correct format

Comment: In general the best way to do that in JDBC is to use a `PreparedStatement` and instances of `java.sql.Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp` depending on the actual datatype of the column). Never pass values as literals

Answer (score 1):

USE **DATE_FORMAT**

The following script uses the DATE_FORMAT() function to display different formats. Example with `now()`

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')


Insert into employeedetails(FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,StartedDate,Salary,CompanyName)  values ('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+job+"',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y'),'"+salary+"','"+company+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the type of `StartedDate` field of your table to format data being inputted

then use specific formatting from type `DATE`,`DATETIME`,`TIMESTAMP`

[The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

by using `DATE_FORMAT` listed above the date and time functions then distinguising the right format for field type

```
DATE_FORMAT($datetoformat,'%Y-%m-%d');   // for date format
DATE_FORMAT($datetoformat,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');  // datetime format
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you are saying your input date looks like

```
12/12/2012
```

but you give

```
'%m-%d-%Y'
```

to STR_TO_DATE. Which is not very plausible to me.

Shouldn't you give

```
'%m/%d/%Y'
```

to STR_TO_DATE?

Answer (score -1):

in php you should use

```
    "Insert into employeedetails(FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,StartedDate,Salary,CompanyName)  values 
('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$job."','".date('d/m/Y')."','".$salary."','".$company."')";
```

Comment: specify the reason -1 for this answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP tagged the question `java`, and the code is obviously not PHP.